# How are you able to factorise a determinant like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, factoring

I'm aware of many different properties of determinants, like two rows being equal implies determinant is zero, or if a row is multiplied by a constant, then you factor out that constant. I'm not aware of being able to do this though. What property am I missing that allows you to simplify a determinant like this?
[image]

Comment: Add the negative second, third and fourth column to the first.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I would add the positive values of the columns, since $1-3x+x+x+x=1$

Comment: @callculus Your'e going from right to left, I from left to right ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Ok.  I'm sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule**: if a matrix $B$ is obtained from $A$ , by adding or subtracting one column to another column (part of  elementary column operation),
Then, these two matrices $A$ and $B$ have equal dets.

Comment: May read: "... by adding or subtracting *a multiple of* one column to another *unchanged* column ..."

Comment: Hmmm,,,,but OP's problem doesn't need those extra thing, that's why I didn't add.

Comment: Didn't know this rule, thanks!